# Any there any tools like Burpsuite that fully support HTTP/2?

Tags: proxy, burp-suite, tampering

Nowadays websites start migrating to HTTP/2, but Burpsuite hasn't fully support HTTP/2 yet. I know HTTPCanary is good and support multiple protocols like replaying HTTP2 and even TCP/UDP, but that only available in Android.

Are there any similar tools that provide the same functionality as Burpsuite that already supports HTTP/2?

Comment: Unfortunately, questions of the type "are there products/services that do X?" are off-topic has the lists could be endless and they don't tend to age well.

Answer (score 2):

Information Security SE isn't really for product recommendations, but the subject is covered pretty well in [Stuart Walker: Testing HTTP/2 only web services](https://www.nccgroup.com/uk/about-us/newsroom-and-events/blogs/2018/may/testing-http2-only-web-services/).

The reason why the tools haven't been developed into this direction is probably because debugging HTTP/2 itself hasn't been that common with such tools. When testing *web application security*, the target isn't the protocol used to transmit the content, but the application. Most servers do support fallback to HTTP/1.1, and you can always put a reverse proxy in front of those that don't.